# How to charge phone with laptop lid closed?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

According to the Windows 8.1 settings on my Inspiron 11 3000 laptop, when I close the lid it should go to sleep mode, and it does.

However, when I close the lid with my phone connected via USB, my phone stops charging.  My older laptop with Windows 7 didn't have this problem. On my old laptop, even with lid closed, the phone would continue to charge.  How do I enable this feature in Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the Inspiron 11 3147 computer, shut down the computer.  Then turn on the computer and keep pressing F2 until the BIOS screen appears.  Then go to the Advance tab. Find `USB wake support` and enable it.  Save the BIOS setting and exit.  Start up windows.  Now you can close the lid of the computer to enter sleep mode and still keep charging your phone via USB.

=============  OR TRY ============ 
Here are the steps to get your external device (USB) charged even when the computer is in sleep mode:

a.    Click Start -> in the start search field type: Device Manager, press enter.
If you are prompted for access either press continue or supply the necessary username and password.

b.    When Device Manager opens, expand the Universal Serial Bus controllers category.

c.    Here you will see several USB Root Hub listings, for each right-click and select Properties.

d.    In the properties window, click Power Management.

e.    Uncheck ‘Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power’, click OK.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks I tried that already and it had no effect.  Phone still doesn't charge when lid is closed and in sleep mode.

Comment: Curious to know if you are able to charge any other USB device when kept in sleep mode.

Comment: Ok I got it to work, and it wasn't a windows thing.  I went into the BIOS settings and found a `USB wake support` and enabled it.  Then I saved the setting and started up windows.  Now when I close the lid to my computer and let the computer go to sleep, I can still keep charging.

Comment: This works because in order for your computer to wake up on USB keyboard or mouse clicks, it needs to provide power to USB devices while it's asleep, otherwise USB keyboards and mice would be unable to announce themselves to the PC.

Answer (score 1):

When laptop lid is closed, by default on Windows 8 it should automatically go to sleep mode - which makes your USB stop working unless you lift the lid up.

To prevent this from happening, simply go to:

1. Control Panel
2. Power Options
3. Click on `Change plan settings` next to selected power plan
4. Click on `Change advanced power settings` text in this window
5. In the Power Options window, search for `Power buttons and lid` settings
6. Under this you will find a `Lid close action` setting
7. From the dropdown menu select `Do nothing` option to prevent your laptop go to Sleep mode when you put down a lid.

Comment: This prevents the laptop going into sleep mode, which will waste battery.  There are likely to be other ways to provide USB power while asleep.  For example, if your computer has a "wake on USB key/mouse" feature, then it MUST provide USB power when the computer is asleep.